# Node Error - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm attempting to write a node module that works with a node package. I'm kind of stuck, and don't know where the problem is. I know the package is being loaded correctly.

The Code Below is referencing the icontrol package 
https://github.com/nfarina/icontrol/blob/master/index.js

```js
// loads the icontrol package
var iControl = require("node-icontrol").iControl;
// these are the paramters you need
// according to this https://github.com/nfarina/icontrol/blob/master/index.js#L19-L22
var config = {
  system: "system name",
  email: "your@email.com",
  password: "kdkdkdkdk",
  pinCode: "pin"
}
// then you will want to initialize it
var mySystem = iControl(config);
// then there are a few calls you can make on mySystem
// 1. getArmState https://github.com/nfarina/icontrol/blob/master/index.js#L56
mySystem.getArmState(function(error, result){
if (error) {
console.error(error);
return
  }
console.log(result);
});
// 2. setArmState https://github.com/nfarina/icontrol/blob/master/index.js#L70
// it looks like the armState param can be "disarm" or "arm"
mySystem.setArmState(armState, function(error){
if (error) {
console.error(error);
return
  }
console.log("Alarm set to:", armState);
});
// 3. subscribeEvents https://github.com/nfarina/icontrol/blob/master/index.js#L96
// this will open a web socket listener that will send a message any
// time the arm state is changed
```

Error I'm receiving

```
mySystem.getArmState(function(error, result){
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getArmState' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Admin/Documents/Test.js:15:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
at startup (node.js:138:18)
at node.js:974:3
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: `iControl` is a constructor. You initialize it with `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the [new](http://var%20mySystem%20=%20iControl(config);) operator. The `iControl` function is meant to be used as a constructor (with new). It doesn't have an explicit `return` statement, so without `new` it returns `undefined`.

Change:

```
var mySystem = iControl(config);
```

To:

```
var mySystem = new iControl(config);
```